# Cordova - jQuery Mobile - Unwanted CSS

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have custom page in app which display wallpaper with text. But on that page, there is always some CSS. I think, its from jquery. My page looks like this:

[image: cordova page]

That white shadow on text. That should not be there and dont know how to get rid of it.

I see now its from this:     `text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f3f3f3;` int `jquery mobile css`

Is it possible to not use jquery mobile css on one page?

Comment: you could simply overwrite the given styles. As you aleardy mentioned a text shadow is set. Therefore just overwrite it in your own styles.

Comment: Just override with text-shadow: none;

Answer (score 0):

Open the css file of jquery mobile and look for every text-shadow, delete them. I don't want to overwrite everything every time I work on an app, so I got rid the text-shadow.